Reviewing Low Quality Answers by New Users that Should be Comments
Sometimes, while I am reviewing posts in the low-quality posts queue, I come across some answers by new users that are actually meant to be comments, i.e., they either ask for clarification of the question from the OP or are merely one-line hints. Now, there are 2 possibilities as to what should be done in such cases:

Recommend the answer for deletion by clicking on "This is commentary on another post, not an answer." option. This will definitely benefit the community, but can have a negative impact on the user and can reduce their willingness to participate due to receiving negative feedback when they are genuinely trying to or asking for help.

Click on the "Looks OK" option, then leave a comment below the answer suggesting them to improve their answer by adding more details if it is a hint, or if the answer asks for clarification, informing them that they can gain reputation points by asking and answering questions and that they gain the privilege to comment anywhere at 50 points.


What is the best practice in such cases?

If it has no value as an answer then "Looks OK" is the wrong option. Don't try to optimize for the OP, optimize for the many visitors.

As answered here a decade ago, "A comment is not an answer and should be deleted" - this still holds true, so I strongly believe only the first one is valid option. "have a negative impact on the user" is not something that should stop us from curating.

@ShadowWizard shouldn't we be welcoming to new users and encourage them to be a part of the site?

@MathGuy we can still leave a comment explaining it's bad, even when choosing "recommend deletion", there's no conflict. It's the same as downvote, in a way: you do something to signal the post is not good, while letting its author know. In case the user is willing to learn, they'll either self delete, and wait until they have enough rep to actually comment, or edit to make it actual answer, then further reviewers can mark it "Looks OK" and save it from deletion. (It requires several "Recommend Deletion" to actually delete a post)

Moderators have the option of convert-to-comment.
After seeing this question I was wondering if there should be an option on the Low Quality Answers queue to allow non-moderators to request the option of converting the answer to a comment.
Searching meta found the comment in Meta Stack Exchange
Allow users with less than 50 rep to comment if they've already commented contains:

NAA to comment conversions happen in <1% of NAAs, and perhaps only 1 percent of those comments are responded to, and 1 percent of the low rep posters ever see the comment to need to respond back. M.A.R.

Where "NAA" means not-an-answer, which is a flag which can be raised on answer that doesn't actually answer the question at hand .
Given what M.A.R. said, don't see the benefit on a feature request to add the option to the Low Quality Answers queue for a convert to comment option.
Therefore, recommending deletion by clicking on "This is commentary on another post, not an answer." option seems appropriate.

You as a reviewer also have the option to convert to a comment, but you have to do it manually (good old copy and paste).
